# BroadcastBlock not working as intended

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I use a `BroadcastBlock` in `TPL Dataflow` which links to `ActionBlocks`. However, I cannot find a bug in my code. I post items to the `BroadcastBlock` via `SendAsync` and when I print the items in the `ActionBlocks` I find that some are missing and mysteriously others are duplicates. I keep track of the order of processed items and thus found that just at the occasion when an item is missing the previous or subsequent items is duplicated (fed to the same `Actionblock` via `LinkTo`). I have no idea what is going on. Here are couple of my code snippets that are relevant:

Here the instantiation of the `BroadCastBlock`:

```
buffer = new BroadcastBlock<Quote>(quote => quote);
```

Here's how I link to action blocks:

```
//Filter for incoming quotes
Predicate<Quote> quoteBroadCastFilter = new Predicate<Quote>(newQuote =>
{
    if (symbol.symbolID == newQuote.symbol.symbolID)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});

//Link Strategy up to BroadCastBlocks
buffer.LinkTo<Quote>(newStrategy.GetStrategyQuoteBuffer(), new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }, quoteBroadCastFilter);
```

This is how I submit items (quote) to the `BroadCastBlock`:

```
buffer.SendAsync(quote);
```

The problem is that when I print out tracking info right before sending via `SendAsync` everything looks perfectly fine. When I print the same information in the `ActionBlock` that `BroadCastBlock` links I observe infrequent errors. I noticed that the missing/duplicate items occur when items are fed to the `BroadCastBlock` very quickly (via `EventHandler` of an API)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A short but complete sample application would be better than a bunch of snippets.

Comment: Well, the problem is its a small component of a much bigger project. Its hard to post the complete code. I whipped up a quick code sample where I just push items into a broad cast block which is linked to an actionblock and it seems that it works just fine. The items are value types (ints) and broadcast blocks indeed guarantees delivery to all linked to blocks. I only conclude from that that when using object types (as I did above) that the content changes before broadcast block performs the cloning of the items...

Comment: ...I am just really confused because right before I SendAsync the object to the broadcast block the order is preserved and no items are skipped or duplicated when I output. However, when I print out the same content within the actionblock, after the item has been sent to the broadcast block and passed on to the actionblock the order is messed up for whatever weird reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question as I found the issue:

Before the item is sent to `BroadCastBlock`, the item (of ref type) is read from a concurrent collection, updated, and then sent. So, it happened that sometimes the next item was already read from the collection and updated while the previous item still points to the same object which is now in the process of being updated. This in short caused the problems with items that were already in the `BroadCastBlock`. There was no problem post `BroadCastBlock` clone but before with items in the input queue.

I had to perform a deep copy of the Quote object before sending it via Post or `SendAsync` to the broad cast block.